# sinon.js: creating a 'stub' for a method and test ignores the stub

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, sinon, stub

I wrote the following code in node.js:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

export async function readSite() {
    try {
        let response = await rp('http://www.google.com');
        return response;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

export async function main() {
    let response = await readSite();
    return response;
}
```

I want to test `main` method. Since `readSite` is an asynchronous method that I don't want to run during the test, I want to mock/stub it, meaning whenever the test call `readSite` method it will automatically get a response (without calling an external website).

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const app = require("./app");

describe('when there was no ingredient', async() => {
    it('mama would be angry', async () => {
        sinon.stub(app, 'readSite').returns(Promise.resolve('blabla'));
        let res = await app.main();
        console.log("*************************************", res);
    })
})
```

When I run the test (run `mocha ./test.js` in terminal), I see that "www.google.com" has been read, and it means that stub has not succeeded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const rp = require("request-promise");

async function readSite() {
  try {
    let response = await rp("http://www.google.com");
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function main() {
  let response = await exports.readSite();
  return response;
}

exports.readSite = readSite;
exports.main = main;
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const app = require(".");

describe("main", () => {
  it("should stub readSite", async () => {
    const readSiteStub = sinon.stub(app, "readSite").resolves("blabla");
    const actual = await app.main();
    expect(actual).to.be.equal("blabla");
    readSiteStub.restore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  main
    ✓ should stub readSite


  1 passing (9ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    77.78 |      100 |       75 |    77.78 |                   |
 index.js      |    55.56 |      100 |       50 |    55.56 |           4,5,6,8 |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59068172

For more info, see: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-214939935

Comment: I ran this code and it seems that the test passes, and still http://www.google.com is read.

Comment: @CrazySynthax It shouldn't. We already stubbed the `readSite` function which means test runner will call the stubbed one and return `blabla` mock data instead of returning the real response data. Otherwise, the assertion will fail. it will cause the test case fail as well.